# java.util.Timer stops without any exception

Tags: java, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I go to the FTP each 2 mins to upload new files.
I implemented it with java.util.Timer. But after some time - several days or even week - it stops without any exception and without any reason.

I found thread:
[Java unlimited thread stops after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596525/java-unlimited-thread-stops-after-some-time)

But there is no particular solution in it.
I read about ScheduledExecutorService, but as far as I understand - it's the same as Timer.

Please give me some ideas!

Comment: Timers run on a sparate thread. if any exception occurs, the thread stops. catch all throwables in run() or similar method, and output it to log.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a default Exception handler using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` API in your main thread and try to log any throwable/exception that could get swallowed silently.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that no one have answered this question, maybe because this is a duplicate.

ScheduledExecutorService uses `System.nanotime()` and Java.util.Timer uses `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` depends up on system time and `System.nanotime()` gives nanoseconds since some fixed arbitrary initial time and is not related to system time. So any change in system time (due to NTP time correction or system stand-by) may or may not impact Timer execution. This would be the reason that your timer fails.

For more details please refer - [What should Timertask.scheduleAtFixedRate do if the clock changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588167/what-should-timertask-scheduleatfixedrate-do-if-the-clock-changes)