# XDEVTextField's value isn't updated to real time

Tags: java, date, time, timer, rapidclipse

I have an XDEVTextField that needs to update real time by every second. I tried the answers proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699413/java-timer-update-every-second/26699423#26699423) question, including using Executor and Swing Timer. I also tried [this way](https://www.javatpoint.com/digital-watch).
Below is my code:

```
public class FirstView extends XdevView implements Runnable {
    Thread t = null;
    String timeString = "";

    public FirstView() {
        super();
        this.initUI();
        this.t = new Thread(this);
        this.t.start();
    }

    @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                 while (true) {
                    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    final Date date = cal.getTime();
                    this.timeString = formatter.format(date);
                    System.out.println(this.timeString);
                    this.txtTime.setValue(this.timeString);
                    Thread.sleep(500); <-- this should be changed to 1000 but I forgot to
                 } 
              }
              catch (final Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
```

The problem is the `txtTime`'s value isn't updated continuously at all, the value was only set once at the point the Thread started
[image: My GUI preview]
 while the `System.out.println(dateandtime.format(date));` can still print out the real time to the console, like this:
[image: The console]

I'm using Rapidclipse 3.1.1. I made a similar digital clock like this one using Java Swing's JLabel on Netbeans. I have no clue what can be the problem here. I suspected and checked all the Properties of the `txtTime` element but nothing seems to be the cause to this. Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may only access an UI using the access() method, which locks the session to prevent conflicts.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                this.time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
                System.out.println(this.time);
                UI.getCurrent().access(()->this.button.setCaption(this.time));
                this.t.sleep(1000);
                
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```