# Java HTTP client getting time from NTP server

Tags: java, sockets, protocols, ntp

I'm trying to write an HTTP client, and I need to get the time from an NTP server I found here: https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

This is my Java code:

```java
String getTime(){
    String time = "";
    try{
        Socket timeSocket = new Socket("time-a-g.nist.gov",37);
        BufferedReader timeIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(timeSocket.getInputStream()));
        time = timeIn.readLine();
        timeSocket.close();
        timeIn.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return time;
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the string I'm getting back is null, can anyone help?

Comment: Just search for "[java] ntp" on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+ntp, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711730/how-can-i-access-ntp-clock-in-java/39309568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP (and UDP) port 37, which you are connecting to, is used for the `TIME` protocol (RFC [868](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc868)). In this protocol, times are sent as a single binary 32bit integer in network byte order.

UDP port 123 is used for the `NTP` protocol (RFCs [1059](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1059), [1119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1119), [1305](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1305), [5905](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5905)). In this protocol, times are sent as a series of binary messages.

You can't read either type of data as text with `BufferedReader.ReadLine()`.

Comment: thanks, how would I be able to read it then?

Comment: For the `TIME` protocol, try `DataInputStream.readInt()`. The `NTP` protocol is vastly more complex.